# How to use rowfilter Operation Like with dataset?

Tags: dataset

I have a problem :

```
DataSet DS ;
DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="[Name] Like '%w[eēéěè]%'";
```

> Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%w[eēéěè]%' is invalid.

```
DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="[Name] Like 'w[eēéěè]*'";
```

> Error in Like operator: the string pattern 'w[eēéěè]*' is invalid.

I do like this

```
DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter="[Name] Like '%w[[]eēéěè[]]%'";
```

it doesn't work

what should I do ?

Comment: Try `[Name] Like '*w[eēéěè]*'`

Comment: Thank u ,..but it still error like operator  the same ....